# SerialPort.list is not a function

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I tried to create an array of port, to which serial devices are connected using the serialport module of nodeJS.
I used the following code, which should in theory work I think:

```
var getPortsList = (callback) => {
    var portsList = [];

    SerialPort.list((err, ports) => {
        ports.forEach((port) => {
            portsList.push(port.comName);
        });

        callback(null, portsList);
    });
};
```

Whenever I execute it tho, I get the following error: `TypeError: SerialPort.list is not a function`.
U tried to google the problem, but could not find anything useful.
Help in any way is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Google: TypeError: SerialPort.list is not a function](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+SerialPort.list+is+not+a+function&oq=TypeError%3A+SerialPort.list+is+not+a+function), finds: [TypeError: serialport.list is not a function](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/1789).  that has also the question: "Can we see your code? At least the part where you are instantiating the board."  which might b useful here too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you import serialport changed in version >= 10:

Below you have two equivalent examples to import serialport module.

Solution #1

```
var sp = require('serialport')

sp.SerialPort.list()
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Solution #2

```
const {SerialPort} = require('serialport')

SerialPort.list()
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

For reference, it's stated here:
https://serialport.io/docs/guide-upgrade#exports

Answer (score 0):

`SerialPort.List` is deprecated from SerialPort core module and moved to `SerialPort/List` as a command tool.

```
npm install @serialport/list
```